# SQL command for min and maximum values in a line

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a Table of TestDataExcel1 containing values of temperature.

I want to show
Min_Temp | Count_Min_Temp | Max_Temp  | count_Max_Temp

This code snippet ;
Select min(Temperature_C) as Min_temp ,
count(Temperature_C) from TestDataExcel1 where Temperature_C =
(select min(Temperature_C) from TestDataExcel1 );
gives me the correct result whereas while intergrating everything in a single query, I get error.

I have written the following query to achieve the above requirement but the DB browser shows an error. Can you help me to find out the error?

Select min(Temperature_C) as Min_temp,
count_Min_Temp As (select count(Temperature_C) from TestDataExcel1
where Temperature_C =(select min(Temperature_C) from TestDataExcel1 )),
max(Temperature_C) as Max_temp , count_Max_Temp as
(select count(Temperature_C) from TestDataExcel1
where Temperature_C =(select max(Temperature_C) from TestDataExcel1))
from TestDataExcel1;

Thanks in advance!

Edited:
I just realised to have jumbled up the syntax and the correct solution is

Select min(Temperature_C) as Min_temp,(select count(Temperature_C) from TestDataExcel1
where Temperature_C =(select min(Temperature_C) from TestDataExcel1 )) As count_Min_Temp,
max(Temperature_C) as Max_temp ,
(select count(Temperature_C) from TestDataExcel1
where Temperature_C =(select max(Temperature_C) from TestDataExcel1))
as count_Max_Temp
from TestDataExcel1;

Answer (score 1):

based on your question and query i assume this will meet your requierments

```
SELECT MIN(Temperature_C) AS Min_temp,
(SELECT COUNT(Temperature_C) WHERE Temperature_C=  MIN(Temperature_C)) AS Count_Min_Temp,
MAX(Temperature_C) AS Max_temp,
(SELECT COUNT(Temperature_C) WHERE Temperature_C=  MAX(Temperature_C)) AS Count_Max_Temp
FROM TestDataExcel1
```

Comment: I tried again with codes that I had jumbled up ; Select min(Temperature_C) as Min_temp,(select count(Temperature_C) from TestDataExcel1
 where Temperature_C =(select min(Temperature_C) from TestDataExcel1 )) As count_Min_Temp,
 max(Temperature_C) as Max_temp ,
(select count(Temperature_C) from TestDataExcel1
 where Temperature_C =(select max(Temperature_C) from TestDataExcel1)) 
 as count_Max_Temp
 from TestDataExcel1; got the correct answer